# <br/> vs <div/> in clearing

Tags: html, xhtml

What is the difference

```
<br style="clear:both;"/>
```

vs

```
<div style="clear:both;"/>
```

??

Also, I thought

```
<div style="clear:both;"/>
```

is a good way of clearing, but is

```
<div style="clear:both;"> </div>
```

a proper way?

Comment: Sorry if you already know this but in some cases you don't need a clearer. If you simply want the parent element to stretch to include the complete floated element you can just set an overflow value on the parent element and it will automatically stretch. I prefer this because you don't need markup

Comment: @Helephant: Can you elaborate on using overflow? I've never used it or heard of it.

Comment: Have a look at this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: @Helephant: thanks! That is a really good tip, assuming that the trick is compatible with all the browsers as it was noted in the article.

Comment: I can vouch for it in IE6, IE7 and Firefox. I'm pretty sure it works in Safari and Opera as well.

Comment: div always works where as sometimes br/hr wont fully clear the float in some cases. Typical IE

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The difference is which *other* style attributes you inherit.  Of course one inherits from `<br>` and the other from `<div>`.

*Typically* `<div>` has no special style implications other than `display:block` whereas `<br>` implies a line-break and some non-zero height (linked to the current font height).

But often (e.g. with the ubiquitous `css-reset` technique) there is approximentally no difference.  Therefore, pick the one that makes the most *semantic* sense.

[UPDATE]

For closing tags, use `<div></div>` and not `<div/>`.  [Here's why](http://dusan.fora.si/blog/self-closing-tags).

Thanks to commentors [Sebastian Celis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65778/sebastian-celis) and [ephemient](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20713/ephemient) for the "closing tag" correction.

Comment: There is a difference with the closing tags. I would not recommend using the self-closing div tag. See http://dusan.fora.si/blog/self-closing-tags

Comment: comment++ Unless you're in XHTML/XML, <div /> has a good chance of not meaning what you think it means.

Comment: I knew <div /> wouldn't work...just couldn't find the page when I needed it!

Comment: The real explanation for which <div /> isn't working is because he's sending text/html Content-Type headers. He's using pseudo-XHTML

Answer (score 10):

This is the style that I use for clearing:

```
.Clear { clear: both; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

Usage:

```
<div class="Clear"></div>
```

This will not take up any extra space in the page as the height is zero.

Internet Explorer has a strange idea that the content of each element has to be at least one character high, and another strange idea that each element should be as high as it's content. Using `overflow: hidden` keeps the content from affecting the size of the element.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't leave a comment explaining why, it's useless.

Comment: This is old.  I'd like to add that I use something similar, only I include `line-height:0;margin:0;padding:0;` and I may set the `font-size` to 0 as well (to affect the line-height). I also keep the name lower case.  I add all that extra so it works cross browsers (and versions).

Comment: @vol7ron: your version is not cross brower, cause `font-size:0` does not work on IE7!

Comment: @MarcoDemaio: Wow old post.  It should work.  I would suspect I didn't highlight that 0 because I didn't add a unit.  Some people work in pixels, I like to work in em's.  So try `0em` or `0px` - it should definitely work in IE7

Comment: @vol7ron: Using zero values without units works just fine, and is specified in the standards. However, setting `line-height`, `font-size` or `padding` is moot when you have `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: Right, I think it was IE6, where that wasn't working for me.  It might have been another browser - thank goodness we no long have to worry about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
<p class="clear"></p>
```

and in your CSS just add:

```
.clear {clear:both; height:0px; font-size:1px;}
/* font-size:0px; does not work well on IE7, it works in IE8 and all other browsers. */
```

You might say, why not:

```
<br class="clear">
```

I typically use the `clear` class after `float:left` elements, and when using the `<br>` instead of the `<p>` they don't seem to work well on IE7 they don't clear as supposed, and on Safari4/Chrome they add unwanted space. I didn't have time to investigtae better this one, so it might be just an error on my design, all I know the `<p>` in this case seem to be more cross-browser.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no difference, depending on inherited styles.

This links says some more, and recommends :
http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 1):

The only difference that I can think of here is that `<div>` is a block-level element, while `<br>` is an inline-level element.

But `<br>` actually behaves somewhat like a block-level element, other than the fact that it is effected by `line-height` and `font-size` CSS properties.

In my opinion, `<br style="clear:both;"/>` is the more proper way to put a line-break in your page, mostly because it is widely-accepted and easily identifiable by others who may not be familiar with your markup.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing (valid) XHTML you don't need to use the closing tag, but self closing div tags don't work in all browsers, so you should still use it. ie your example:

```
`<div style="clear:both;"> </div>`
```

This is valid XHTML (see [html vs xhtml](http://www.w3schools.com/XHTML/xhtml_html.asp)) but doesn't work in all browsers, so you should stick with the above:

<s>`<div style="clear:both;" />`</s>

also, For what it's worth the `<br>` tag is deprecated in favor of the `<line>` tag (see [w3.org entry on the `<br/>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-xhtml2-20020805/mod-text.html#sec_8.5.))

Comment: No, I believe you were originally correct. While technically the spec says divs can be self-closing, some browsers do not like it.

http://dusan.fora.si/blog/self-closing-tags

Comment: hmm... So should I change it back? Also, This is an interesting thread on whether we should even USE xhtml: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/12026.htm

Comment: The entire situation is less than ideal thanks to some browser vendors and their refusal to fully support XHTML. I usually recommend that only tags which are always self-closed in XHTML be self-closed (img, br, input, etc). Everything else should be closed normally.

Comment: I don't understand why we're getting downmodded :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what I always use:

```
<style type="text/css">
.clearing {
height: 0;
line-height: 0;
font-size: 0;
clear: both;
overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
```

And where I need a clearing:

```
<div class="clearing"></div>
```

You may also be interested in self-clearing containers: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

**EDIT**: Added "overflow:hidden" per the suggestion from another answer poster.

Comment: Maybe somebody likes their answer better and voted me down just for the heck of it.  Oh well...

Answer (score 0):

You do need to be careful about the / on the tag.

I had problems with the slash on the <script> tag terminated by <script language="javascript" src="MyScripts.js" /> way.  Although, most xml compliant parsers would accept both.

<script> has to be terminated by </script>

Answer (score 0):

.clear { clear: both; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; height: 0px; overflow:hidden; }

Usage

"br" sometimes has side-effects in Opera and IE browsers, so you should avoid using it

Answer (score 0):

`<br />` is an inline element, where as `<div>` is a block element. Anyway, I personally prefer to use `<hr class="clear">`, I feel it is more semantically adequate.

Answer (score 0):

All methods are bad. Use CSS to change the appearance of your page. There are many methods to accomplish the same with CSS. Such as giving "overflow: hidden;" on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use..

---

with added CSS rules it can do the job, and it serves this purpose.

Comment: I think your answer is embedded into the site. I'm guessing that you suggested using hr tag :)